# javascriptのオブジェクトがnamespaceであることを確認する方法

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

`google.visualization.data`について検索するとこれが静的なメソッドを格納する`namespace`だということがわかりました。

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data

ですがFirefoxのConsoleで確認した所たんなるObjectだということしかわかりませんでした。

```
google.visualization.data
Object { avg: gvjs_qq(a), count: gvjs_pq(a), group: gvjs_rq(a, b, c), join: function (a, b, c, d, e, f), max: function (a), min: function (a), month: function (a), sum: gvjs_oq(a) }
```

`google.visualization.data`が`namespace`であることをConsole上で確認する方法はありますか？
それとも静的メソッドを格納するためのオブジェクトを`namespace`と呼称しているだけで`namespace`という方があるわけではないのでしょうか？

Comment: javascriptではプリミティブな型以外は基本的にほぼObject型です。詳しい説明は別途他の方の回答に任せますが、リンク先のnamespaceは単純に、名前空間の意味で捉えると良いと思います。

Comment: namespaceという型や概念を持つのではなく、Objectをただそういう用途で使っているということなのですね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

静的なメソッドやプロパティを格納するための、Object以外のインスタンスでないオブジェクトをネームスペースと呼ぶことができます。
例えば、MathはObjectを除く何かのインスタンスではないので、ネームスペースです。
一方、windowはWindowのインスタンスなので、ネームスペースとは呼びにくいです。